# What are Degree and Order of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What  are Degree and Order of a differential equation?

I started reading ODE. I encountered this topic. But I saw there are many cases when Degree can not be determined.

So can anyone explain the following questions extensively?  I want to understand ------

1) What are they?

2) Why they were introduced?

3) When  either Degree or order or both can not be determined?

What I understood:  $\log (\frac{dy}{dx})^2 + 7 (\frac{dy}{dx})^2\ cosx(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2})^2  +xy \ cosxy $

I can say that the order of this differential equation is 2. But Degree can not be determined as $\ cos(x(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2})^2)$ is an infinite series of $x(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2})^2$.

Have I gone wrong anywhere?

Comment: Are you sure it is not

$$
\color{blue}{\left[\cos x \right]} \color{red}{\left(\frac{{\rm d}^2y}{{\rm d}x^2}\right)^2}
$$
?

Comment: The order is useful as it equals the number of boundary conditions you will need. First degree leaves you hopeful that you can solve it. Higher degrees signals its time to move on to the next problem!!!

Comment: edited..Please have a look.@caverac